# Container Instance with openVPN does not run correctly

Tags: azure, docker-compose, openvpn, azure-container-instances, azure-devops-pipelines

I am trying to run a Azure Container Instance with openVPN inside to connect to an external site. I have now managed to make a setup where I use docker-compose to handle the setup.

The container works when I run it locally (with openvpn establishing a vpn connection), and the Azure DevOps pipeline also builds and push to Azure Container Registry.

BUT when I try to run a Container Instance on the image nothing happens, and if I try to run my script interactively I get an error stating basically that there is no connection.

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this?

My azure-pipelines.yml look like this:

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: '*****************************'
  imageRepository: 'getstatus'
  containerRegistry: 'composeproject.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'


stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)

    - task: DockerCompose@0
      inputs:
        containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
        azureSubscription: 'Composeproject'
        azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"composeprojectsrc.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/*********************/resourceGroups/RG-ComposeprojectCloud/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/composeprojectscr"}'
        dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
        action: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
        dockerComposeCommand: 'up -d'
```

In my docker file I run the following command which should make the openVPN connection:

```
CMD openvpn --config config/fremsyn.ovpn --daemon  --auth-user-pass config/login.txt --askpass config/password.conf \
&& ["python3" , "src/cli/getStatus.py"]
```

And the docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: "3.3"
services: 
  getstatus:
    image: composeproject.azurecr.io/getstatus:v1
    restart: always
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
    cap_add: 
      - NET_ADMIN
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun
    volumes:
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
```